# How to avoid internal calculation error in Excel VBA type Double math operation?

Tags: excel, vba

From Excel 2007, I came up with this VBA code when reading this website: [Convert Decimal to Binary fraction](https://indepth.dev/posts/1019/the-simple-math-behind-decimal-binary-conversion-algorithms#:%7E:text=Converting%20decimal%20fraction%20to%20binary&text=To%20convert%20fraction%20to%20binary,fractional%20part%20equal%20to%20zero.)
The main goal is to come up with a function that will convert fractional numbers into binary representation.
Here is my code:

```
Sub DTBfraction() ' Decimal to Binary
Dim myFraction As Double
Dim tmpDEC As Double, tmpPRO As Double, tmpREM As Double
Dim i As Long
Dim tmpSTRING As String, tmpBIT As String
myFraction = 0.8
tmpDEC = myFraction
        Do
            i = i + 1
            tmpDEC = tmpDEC * 2
            tmpPRO = Int(tmpDEC)
            tmpREM = tmpDEC - tmpPRO
            tmpBIT = IIf(tmpPRO >= 1, "1", "0")
            tmpSTRING = tmpSTRING & tmpBIT
            If i > 2000 Then Stop ' needed to prevent cases of infinite looping
            
Debug.Print i, myFraction, tmpDEC, tmpPRO, tmpREM
            
            tmpDEC = tmpREM
        Loop Until tmpREM <= 0
        
Debug.Print "0b0." & tmpSTRING
End Sub

Rem  Debug.Print  i  myFraction   tmpDEC            tmpPRO   tmpREM
Rem  Debug.Print  1     0.8        1.6                 1       0.6
Rem  Debug.Print  2     0.8        1.2                 1       0.2
Rem  Debug.Print  3     0.8        0.4                 0       0.4
Rem  Debug.Print  4     0.8        0.800000000000001   0       0.800000000000001
Rem  Debug.Print  5     0.8        1.6                 1       0.600000000000001
Rem  Debug.Print  6     0.8        1.2                 1       0.200000000000003
Rem  Debug.Print  7     0.8        0.400000000000006   0       0.400000000000006
' ...       up to 52 in that particular case
Rem  Debug.Print    0b0.1100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

The problem encountered is that at the 4 looping, instead of getting 0.8 the code will calculate 0.800000000000001   which create an undesirable behavior of looping many times until the condition will terminate the loop until tmpREM attain a value so small that it is considered 0.
In reality the loop should remain infinite, for, never will tmpREM become zero. It's a periodic situation.

After some experimentation and testings it was discovered that the first 3 tmpREM values of 0.6 0.2 0.4  are not. Instead they are a tiny bit higher but not showing on the Debug.Print line but could be detected if a test is performed such as tmpREM > 0.6    , in fact tmpREM = 0.6 will show a False status.

The goal would be to programmatically catch such situations so that the code stop spiting out 1's and 0's ad-infinitum, but my solution is one of an amateur and not functional. I was trying to multiply the result with 10^12 , do an INT() and devise by 10^12. Not a workable solution. Substraction dont work either, instead of ending up with 0.8 VBA spit out 0.799999999999.
I feel like the solution lies in preventing the calculation error from spitting out a value of 0.80000000000001 instead of 0.8

Once achieved, I would probably be able to come up with a solution to detect periodic calculations and stop the code from looping. At this point I am out of imagination. Hence the question:
How can I get rid of this computational error such that I get 0.8 instead of 0.800000000000001 ?

Comment: @Progman , That is exactly what I was looking for. Lot's of good solutions in this post. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Certain numbers in binary have infinite "decimals", very similar to e.g. 1/3 and 1/7 in decimal.
Those numbers cannot be represented exactly in binary; one such is 1/10

In decimal you may round to n decimals with:

> n=1
> numff=int(num*10^n+0.5)/10^n

... but that also has limits when you raise n to higher numbers; again due to numeric precision in computers.